# QR Code generation in shell / mac terminal

Tags: perl, shell, terminal, applescript, image-events

I want to create QR codes for a project I'm working on in [applescript](/questions/tagged/applescript) the resulting qr will be placed in the indesign document. I have found that there is a plugin for indesign but I suspect that requires user interaction.

So I've been search for how to generate the qr using a shell command. I've found things related to php and rails and even coldfusion but none of those will fit the bill on this. I need to generate them using shell command so image events or perl basically anything I can run from the command line that comes with the mac os

thanks for your help.

**antotheer**

I wonder if I could call a url using curl or somthing to get one ?

Comment: If you try a [search on the CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/search?query=qrcode&mode=all) you'll find a few options including a nice wrapper for the C library mentioned by Dave: [Imager::QRCode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Imager::QRCode)

Comment: @ashley thanks for the link I'll have to look through those and see if there is something i like

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For doing something similar, we use [libqrencode](http://fukuchi.org/works/qrencode/index.en.html).

It's a c library for generating QR codes, but it comes with a command line utility (called qrencode) which lets you generate QR codes from a string, e.g.:

`./qrencode -o /tmp/foo.png "This is the input string"`

It supports most options you'd probably want (e.g. error correction level, image size, etc.).

We've used it in production for a year or two, with no problems.

I've only run it on linux systems, but there's no reason you shouldn't be able to compile it on Mac OS, assuming you have a compiler and build tools installed (and any libraries it depends on of course).

Comment: that looks promising though I was hoping for something I do without having to compile anything I'm not good at that stuff lol, but I we can't always get what we want right ?

Comment: on mac os you can get it through homebrew: brew install libqrencode

Answer (score 30):

As  [Riccardo Cossu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352109/riccardo-cossu) mentioned please use homebrew:

```
brew install qrencode
qrencode -o so.png "http://stackoverflow.com"
```