# How would one render a QR code in the logs of a GitHub workflow?

Tags: utf-8, ascii, qr-code

I need to show a QR code in a terminal (output/logs) this needs to use ASCII or UTF-8 characters. My team makes use of the [GitHub app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.github.android) to collaborate, and a QR code in the logs of the jobs will help us quickly scan and jump to a specific job or artifact that is generated during the workflow when we are in the same room.

I am aware of tools that were mentioned in similar questions like [QR Code generation in shell / mac terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6215030) but the answer actually does not produce a QR code in the terminal, instead it produces a PNG image you are then supposed to open and view. This is not an option in the CI. While I can make use of the `GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY` it requires additional steps that need to be added to the workflow and that seems like overkill.

Comment: thanks for the insightful `edit` @jonrsharpe   
I will take this into account for the next time I post a question